# Binomial Test in R

Tags: r

I need to do a bernoulli test in R. So im aware that its effectively a binom test in similar format

```
binom.test(x, n, p = 0.5,
alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
conf.level = 0.95)
```

I have two possible outcomes for my scenatio which are 0 or 1 so i assume the probability to be 0.3 or 0.7. Im just unsure exactly how to code this in R.  Thanks for any help

Comment: This is likely better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: could you be a little bit more specific about the form of your data and the hypothesis you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

Statistical hypothesis testing is depend on your assumption about data. Suppose you are in believe that 1 appear in data more than 0.7 of the times. So there are two possible condition:

H0: The appearance of 1 in data is more than 0.7
H1: The appearance of 1 in data is less than 0.7

So you are about to test H0 (null hypothesis) against H1(alternative hypothesis). In this condition the binomial test is:

```
binom.test(
  table(factor(levels = c(1,0), x=data)),
  p = 0.7,
  alternative =  'less')
```

and the output data is something like:

```
data:  table(factor(levels = c("true", "false"), x = data))
number of successes = 42587, number of trials = 64000, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is less than 0.7
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.000000 0.668492
sample estimates:
  probability of success 
0.6654219
```

As you can see the p-value is grater than 0.05 so the H0 is accepted.